# Define a custom layer with 2 tensors inputs in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, layer

I would like to implement a custom layer. The 2 inputs of my custom layer are 2 tensors, which come from 2 seperate 2D convolution layers, is there an example?

Comment: Would you be able to rewrite your function using keras backend functions? If you try using numpy, you'll not have a connectoin for backpropagation. --- The choice between Lambda or Custom Layer depends on whether you want trainable weights in the layer or not. (If it's pure calculation, use Lambda).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer Daniel. I would like to have a backpropagation yes. The layer I would like to implement is the proposal layer in the Faster rcnn Network. So there is nothing trainable. My confusion is, how can I have backpropagation if I don't have weights?

Comment: You don't need weights (well, the entire model needs weights somewhere, but not every layer). But for keeping the (automatic) backpropagation intact, you need keras backend functions (or tensorflow/theano functions) directly on the tensors. Using numpy will break the connection.

Comment: Ok, this makes it clearer. Seeing the implementation of the function rpn_to_roi hat I would like to have as a layer. Would you say, that I can use keras backed functions for this ? If yes, could you maybe give me a link to a similar example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't need it to be trainable, a lambda function will also do. Or you can keep the custom layer as you have it, and set trainable to False. The weights will never be updated for this layer, and whatever you do here will forward propagate to the next layer in the model and as mentioned in the comments, backprop will impact the other layers with weights. So, definitely your model will learn something.

I personally recommend using a custom layer, if you decide later to add some learning to this layer and check your results. You cannot do this in a Lambda function. If you add one (kernel), you will have to use in the 'call' method. Your model will throw an error during training otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Ajjo. But Do I have to reimplement the rpn_to_roi function using backend functions instead of numpy functions to have backpropagation in the case of using a custom layer as well?

Comment: Yes. You will have to use the backend functions.

Comment: ok. so for example the line: ** anchor_x = (anchor_size * anchor_ratio[0])/C.rpn_stride**  would be  implemented like this ** anchor_x = K.dot(K.dot(anchor_size, anchor_ratio[0]), K.variable(value= 1/C.rpn_stride)) ** ? Is this right?

Comment: For elementwise multiplication, for additions, divisions, etc., you can use the standard symbols: `anchor_size*anchor_ratio[0]` for instance. The `K.dot` is for matrix multiplication, not elementwise multiplication.

Comment: Yes. Something like that. You can get more info of the methods from the Keras documentation.

Comment: ok. An dwhat is about np.maximum, np.delete, np.arange ? Or to make it more understandable, which operations among the ones used in my function  HAVE to be reimplemented with backends?

Comment: You can continue using the numpy functions as long as they are do with any operation to the array. For eg, np.sum(), np.argmax(), np.exp(), np.log() etc. For the backend, you need tensors which can be updated and used in the model. keras.backend lets you do that. keras.backend.reshape() for instance, returns a tensor which is something that the backend (say tensorflow) understands. I strongly suggest you read the documentation and the samples to get a better idea. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okey, so that means, that I can keep everything as it is and just change the type of the output variable of the function  rpn_to_roi as follows : result = K.variable(value = non_max_suppression_fast(all_boxes, all_probs, overlap_thresh=overlap_thresh, max_boxes=max_boxes)[0]) ? Is this right ?

Comment: No. You will have to use the backend functions. The input to the call method is a tensor too.